# Passing ID parameters to a function

Tags: jquery, function, syntax

I'm hoping this is a simple syntax issue.
I have a number of items on a page. When clicked, the id of each item should be passed to jquery. This will then cause an opaque layer with more details to appear.
I'm struggling to get the value of the id into the script.

Can anyone help please?
This is part of the form:

```
<ul class="foodmenu">
    <li class="foodmenuitems"><img src="images/classic.png" id="classic" /></li>
    <li class="foodmenuitems"><img src="images/blue.png"  id="blue"/></li>
</ul>
```

and the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".food-item-details").hide();
    $(".foodmenuitems").click(function() {
        $(".food-item-details").hide();
        var foodItem = $(this).value;
        $(foodItem).show('slow');
    });
    $(".close").click(function() {
        $(".food-item-details").hide('slow');
    });
});
```

Any advice gratefully received!

Answer (score 4):

What you probably wanted is `var foodItem = '#' + this.id;` - only form inputs have a `value`.

However, this still cannot work since IDs need to be unique. You can easily fix it by using data attributes though:

```html
<ul class="foodmenu">
    <li class="foodmenuitems"><img src="images/classic.png" data-item="classic" /></li>
    <li class="foodmenuitems"><img src="images/blue.png"  data-item="blue"/></li>
</ul>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".food-item-details").hide();
    $(".foodmenuitems").click(function() {
        $(".food-item-details").hide();
        var foodItem = $(this).data('item');
        $('#' + foodItem).show('slow');
    });
    $(".close").click(function() {
        $(".food-item-details").hide('slow');
    });
});
```

This code now displays the element with the ID specified in `data-item` when clicking it.

Comment: "However, this still cannot work since IDs need to be unique." I'm failing to see why - `classic` and `blue` seem unique to me.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: He's trying to show another element based on that ID. And from the code he posted he does not have some prefix for the target elements - so they most likely have the same ID like the menu item.

Comment: Thanks all. I'd seen the data-item method before but did'nt understand it. Although this code makes sense I'll have to look it up. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, I've tried to implement the code above but cannot get it to work. Adding alerts to the code suggests that the function executes the second `$(".food-item-details").hide();`but then stops. The close part works okay. If you would like to see the code in full I have posted it at: http://www.holtworth.net/liberty/menu-fragment.txt Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay, so I haven't really got any further with this. Looking over the previous answers, it seems worth pointing put that the target elements have unique id's as well. In fact I've copied and pasted the code above but cannot get it to work. Is there no way to pass parameters from an onclick function into jQuery?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the IDs of the target elements in your question.

Comment: In the example "classic" and "blue" (although there are others). Is it because they aren't numbers? I tried using them and got a little further. I've just updated the text file if that is any use

Comment: That's just what I thought. So you have two elements with the same ID which is not allowed.

Comment: I see what you mean about the prefix now! But still not working. Prefixing the id with "liberty-" and targetting with `var foodItem = 'liberty-'+$(this).data('item');
        $(foodItem).show('slow');` ought to work?